# Get the Map Values into one List after

Tags: apex

I have the for loop on ObjectTerritory2Association object. After for loop run, I put the key and the values into the map. Below is the debug which I get, it returns multiple maps but ins most of the cases keys and the values are the same. Is there any chance that somehow substitute all duplicate Keys and values into one list? But if there are different values into Values() they should be semilolon separated. The final result should be something like:

mapAccountToFranchiseDel{0016w00000XvDZlAAN=Surgical, 0016w00000XvXIEAA3=Surgical, 0016w00000XxCy9AAF=Vision Care;Surgical}

OR

0016w00000XvDZlAAN=Surgical,
0016w00000XvXIEAA3=Surgical,
0016w00000XxCy9AAF=Vision Care;Surgical

Thanks a lot for your help.

[image: Debug Results]

```java
Map<Id, String> mapAccountToFranchiseDel = new Map<Id, String>();

for(ObjectTerritory2Association objTerr :[SELECT Id, objectId, Territory2.Franchise_AC__c FROM ObjectTerritory2Association WHERE objectId IN :accMap.keySet() AND Territory2.Franchise_AC__c != null]){
    mapAccountToFranchiseDel.Put(objTerr.ObjectId, objTerr.Territory2.Franchise_AC__c);

    system.debug('mapAccountToFranchiseDel' + mapAccountToFranchiseDel);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you want a `Map<Id, List<String>>` instead, so that you have an id mapping to a list of String values.

And in your loop, you will need to check whether that key exists on the map or not. If it doesn't, create a new entry for an empty list. Then after that, add the current iteration's String to the list. Something like this:

```java
for (Item i : list) {
  if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
    map.put(key, new List<String>());
  }
  map.get(key).add(item.value);
}
```